# Change the warning message

Tags: commerce

how to change the message "you must be logged in to place an order." I can not find in the rules and in the translation? thank you
[image]

Comment: You're going to need to add more detail. It doesn't look like this message is emitted by core Commerce. What module are you using to accomplish this?

Comment: sorry, I have found. The message comes from the "https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_redirect" module. To change, we must change the parameter module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, what you'll want to do is set this variable: `commerce_checkout_redirect_message`. This variable is used by the module to populate the message.

For example:

```
variable_set('commerce_checkout_redirect_message', 'You must log in to continue.');
```